# php regex parsing parameters from a string

Tags: php, regex

i need to parse parameters from a string using regex.

my example string:

```
'my page',1234,'main', '800,600', 45
```

desired output:

```
Array(
[0] => my page
[1] => 1234
[2] => main
[3] => 800,600
[4] => 45
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you have is comma-separated values. Perhaps [`str_getcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) will serve you better, since it can already account for commas which are inside of quoted strings.

```
print_r(str_getcsv("'my page',1234,'main', '800,600', 45", ',', "'"));
Array
(
    [0] => my page
    [1] => 1234
    [2] => main
    [3] => 800,600
    [4] =>  45
)
```

This doesn't trim the space before the "45" in item 4, but if that's necessary, we can use `array_map()` and `trim()`.

```
print_r(array_map('trim', str_getcsv("'my page',1234,'main', '800,600', 45", ',', "'")));
Array
(
    [0] => my page
    [1] => 1234
    [2] => main
    [3] => 800,600
    [4] => 45
)
```